# Excel 2010 on Windows 10 does not save changes

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

I got reports from Excel 2010 and 2013 users that they open some Excel document, make changes (add, delete or update), save the document and then probably send it through Outlook. The problem is when the go back to the same file to work again, they don't find their work from before BUT when they open the attached excel file they sent they find all their work, nothing lost.

Is it something related to auto-recovery in office? The issue is currently reported in excel only, nothing wrong in Word. I really can't think of anything to troubleshoot. What could be the reason? any troubleshooting tips?

Update: All files are saved locally on the hard disk, no network or cloud storage.

Comment: What you describe seems impossible. I suggest to examine well the installed applications/extensions and the working habits of the users.

Comment: Did this problem appear in a specific file? Do users get any messages when try to save the file?

Comment: They seem to get excel stopped responding sometimes.